# Laravel Throttle message

Tags: laravel, throttling

I'm using ThrottleRequest to throttle login attempts.
In Kendler.php i have

```
'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
```

and my route in web.php

```
Route::post('login', ['middleware' => 'throttle:3,1', 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@authenticate']);
```

When i login fourth time, it return status 429 with message  'TOO MANY REQUESTS.' 
 (by default i guess)
But i just want to return error message, somethings like:

```
return redirect('/login')
            ->withErrors(['errors' => 'xxxxxxx']);
```

Anybody help me! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can either extend the middleware and override the `buildException()` method to change the message it passes when it throws a `ThrottleRequestsException` or you can use your exception handler to catch the `ThrottleRequestsException` and do whatever you want.

so in `Exceptions/Handler.php` you could do something like

```
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\ThrottleRequestsException;

public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof ThrottleRequestsException) {
      //Do whatever you want here.
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, i overrode the buildException and it's working. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Or **since Laravel 8** you can do it in the new style:

Renderable in the register method in **app\exceptions\Handler.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\ThrottleRequestsException;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
 
/**
 * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
 */
public function register(): void
{
    // Create a renderable
    // see https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/errors#rendering-exceptions
    $this->renderable(function (ThrottleRequestsException $e) {
        return redirect('/login')
            ->withErrors(['errors' => 'xxxxxxx']);
    });
}
```